# Is this inductive proof valid?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

Show that $n!>3^n$ for $n \ge 7$

My attempt:

Let the statement $P_n$ say that $n!>3^n$.

**Base Case**

Let $n=7$, then $P_7$ says that $7! > 3^7 \implies 5040>2187$

**Inductive Step**

Fix $k \ge 7$ Assume that $P_k$ is true, that is, $k!>3^k$

Show that $P_{k+1}$ is true,

**This is where I'm concerned I may be wrong.  Am I allowed to do what follows? Or must I always build my proof from the inductive step?**

$(k+1)>3^{k+1} \implies k!(k+1)>3^k \cdot 3$

By our inductive step, we know that $k!>3^k$.  Also, $(k+1)>3$ because $k \ge 7$

~My attempted proof ends here.  The texts answer is shown below:

The answer for the inductive step is as follows;

$(k+1)!=(k+1)k!>(k+1)3^k$
**this next part I don't really get.  Why 7? It's not proving anything for any values greater than 7.**
$\ge(7+1)3^k=8\cdot3^k>3\cdot3^k=3^{k+1}$

Comment: We know $(k+1)>3$ since we assume $k\geq7$. And by the IH, $k!>3^k$. Thus we get $k!(k+1)>3^k \cdot 3 \iff (k+1)>3^{k+1}$ proving the claim. That would be the valid way to use induction and notice we use the fact that $k\geq7$. The answer below shows why we start with 7 and nothing lower.

Comment: You can do this very concisely after the inductive step by writing:

$$(k \ge 7 > 3) \land (k! > 3^k) \implies (k + 1)! = (k + 1) \cdot k! > 3 \cdot k! > 3^{k+1}$$

Comment: With due respect to all of you, please clear my doubt. The inductive step started from "$(k+1)>3^{k+1}\Rightarrow \cdots$" Why and how one is so much sure about it ? Even if k-7 then shall we get $7+1 > 3^{7+1}$ ?

Comment: ohh sorry i didn't see the conclusion . Apologize :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all logical and legitimate. Why 7? Just because the statement is not true for $n < 7$. Say, for $n = 6$, $6! = 720 < 729 = 3^6$.

Don't feel weird about what you consider to be correct. If you are asked to prove the same statement for $n \geq 10^{100}$, which is certainly true, the steps will be exactly the same.

Comment: Ah, so what I did is also perfectly acceptable?

Comment: In my opinion, yes.